# How do I get all the questions answered by a learner by using django queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model named Quiz. Each Quiz has a set of related questions in the model Quiz_Question.

Quiz Model:-

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    quiz_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Quiz_Question Model:-

```
class Quiz_Question(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, related_name='questions')
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Now I can get all the questions for a particular quiz using the related_name attribute as follows:-

```
all_quizes = Quiz.objects.all()
```

A particular quiz:-

```
quiz = all_quizes[0]
```

All the questions related to this quiz as follows:-

```
all_related_questions = quiz.questions.all()
```

I have another model as a LearnerQuestionAnswer where learner is a normal django user:-

```
class LearnerQuestionAnswer(models.Model):
    quiz_question = models.ForeignKey(Quiz_Question)
    learner = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

What I want to do is find out all the questions that are related to the particular quiz by that user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to filter `Quiz_Question` by `quiz` and `learnerquestionanswer__learner` fields:

```
quiz = all_quizes[0]
learner= User.objects.get(id=1)
Quiz_Question.objects.filter(quiz=quiz, learnerquestionanswer__learner=learner)
```

Comment: Is there any similar way where I can do filter on LearnerQuestionAnswer   model?

Comment: @ShashishekharHasabnis yes you can query LearnerQuestionAnswer  same way. For example to filter by Quiz use: `LearnerQuestionAnswer.objects.filter(quiz_question__quiz=quiz)`. Check this doc about span relationships: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships